# Flash preload fails in middle

Tags: flash, preloader

Flash preload fails in middle how to find the failure and make re-request

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of your code? How are you preloading, and what type of file are you preloading?  I'm assuming swf, but you never know.  AS2 or AS3?

In AS3, you'll probably need to listen for an error event that's dispatched by whatever method you're using to preload, and then handle that error accordingly to try again.  You'd probably want some type of attempt counter to avoid getting stuck in a loop trying to load a file that's not there.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Add event listeners for errors on the loader. Errors to look for are IOError and SecutiryError.

**Solution 2:**
Install Tamper Data in Firefox and look at the requests to try and figure out WHY it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **loadClip** method to preload your movieclip. loadClip has error-handling that will enable you to diagnose what's going on.

Documentation:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001189.html